# Building Comprehension based simple Q&A Python model, without the need for training

Tags: python

Here's the approach I've in mind:

- Break the data paragraph such that each sentence is a string.
- Find the keywords in the question (nouns, verbs and adjectives)
  perhaps using POS tagging. Lemmatization might be necessary.
- Search through all the data strings to find the one which has all/most of these keywords. That sentence would most probably be the answer we're looking for.

But, I find the implementation difficult as I'm new to Python and am unaware of the necessary commands/libraries. I will be grateful if someone can guide me down this path or any better way to do it.

Comment: If you're new to python, jumping into NLP is quite a stretch. SO is for help with coding questions, so search the web for common ML libraries, and comeback when you're stuck with the implementation. [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter1/1) is a popular NLP library with a good intro course, but you'll need to know python and it helps knowing PyTorch or TensorFlow

Comment: I work on MATLAB on a daily basis so haven't got a chance to use Python beyond the usual loops and lists. But, I'm assigned this project particularly on Python and am supposed to work without using any training algorithms like Haystack. So, I see no alternative but to learn as I move through